# Create MySQL InnoDB dumps with bulk inserts?

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I need to speed up the import of a sql.gz file into mysql. I have turned off foreign key checking and followed [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html).

#### My question is:

Is there a way to make the export file (the sql.gz) from mysqldump user multi-insert statements like this:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable 
VALUES (1,2), (5,5), ...;
```

so that the bulk loading process will be much faster?

Comment: Have a look at this backup tool (quick backup for a big databases) - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-administration.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqldump does this by default.  There are many other options (such as use REPLACE or INSERT IGNORE as opposed to the default INSERT command) run mysqldump --help to see the list.

You might try LOAD DATA INFILE to see if that is faster.  That will read the data from a tab delimited text file without any INSERT commands.  You would use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' as one way to create this data file.